# Convert BOOK.XML to HTML format using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, jquery-xml

How I will convert `book.xml` file which is attached in my solution to XML string like:

`<book><name>C++</name><price>170</price></book>`

Actually I need to convert `book.xml` file to JSON data. There are many examples which is converting XML string to JSON. but not XML file `book.xml` to `JSON`. Can anybody please help me to convert a specific XML file to XML string.

Comment: Please add a sample of your input file and a sample of the output you want. It's not clear whether you want the output to be XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

check the below links you will get to know how to convert xmltoJson..

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Comment: Sir i need to convert from XML file. in seocond url its taking param as xml string. but i have BOOK.xml file. plz help